How does Next.JS handle Full Route and Data Cache during build?
Using Next.JS 14 with App Router and a custom cache handler using Redis.
My question is regarding the deployment of a self-hosted Next.JS application. We have a lot of API calls (approx. 100.000) which lead to a build time of >1h when we have an empty cache. With a filled cache the build time is reduced by about a fifth.
We are using Redis as cache handler for our application.
I find it very confusing as the Documentation says that both the data cache and the full route cached are persistent on the server. So does a custom cache handler handles both these caches or just the data cache. When running my application I can see that most of the cache entry have the type "FETCH" but I also see some with the type "PAGE" or "ROUTE" so I'm pretty sure it handles both caches.
But this seems wrong to me as written here the cache cleared on redeployment and I expect the Redis instance to be available across deployments.
If it would contain both caches building a new version of my app would also overwrite the full route cache of my running app, which will lead to errors?
Or is the approach to use the Redis cache from my deployed app for the build of a new version? Or is this issue handled by the build ID?
Update:
To clarify my confusion I've prepared an example.

I have a product overview in my application.
During initial build only the fetch requests are stored in Redis
After starting the App (next start) and visiting the app another entry in Redis is added with a key matching the route (in my case /products).
Afterwards I changed the content of my page (Change h2 text).
During rebuild the entry in Redis does not change.
After re-running the app the entry is not changed and the page looks just like the old version. The content of my h2 does not change but stays the same.

